# Why does the compiler complain for this example?

Tags: c

I'm reading about [Typedef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef) on wikipedia. Example mentioned on that page is

```
typedef int km_per_hour ;
typedef int points ;

km_per_hour current_speed ;
points high_score ;
...

void congratulate(points your_score) {
if (your_score > high_score)
...
```

Going further it says this which I'm not able to understand why?

```
void foo() {
unsigned int a;         // Okay
unsigned km_per_hour b; // Compiler complains
long int c;             // Okay
long km_per_hour d;     // Compiler complains
...
```

Why does the compiler complain for unsigned and long?

Comment: Note that typedefs aren't the same as macros.

Comment: Just like signed and unsigned cannot be used with user defined types (like structures), they cannot be used with typedef's also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot prepend `signed` or `unsigned` before a `typedef`'d type. `signed` and `unsigned`  can only modify basic integer types and do that directly.

The compiler parses `signed` or `unsigned` either alone or near `char`, `short`, `int` and `long`. In all other cases they are considered invalid/unexpected/misplaced.

In that sense, `signed` and `unsigned` don't work as `const` or `volatile` modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

`typedefs` can not be modified or used like `macros`. You have `km_per_hour` as an `int`, so it can be used only as such!

You should either change the definition of the `typedefs` or define new ones to get rid of the compiler problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the typedef with an extra specifier.
You should write only km_per_hour b; and km_per_hour d;
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have defined a type - i.e put the sword into the ground and made your case.

You cannot then go about and change your case. That does not work in a court of law nor in a compiler.

Sorry for the metaphor.